# need to convert number to string with nvl and to_char in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

I'm trying to write a query that will give me all the info from my departments table and join with employees table to get the names of the managers of all departments. I can get them except for one department with no manager, and for that I need to print out "no manager". I have tried using nvl and to_char in a WHERE clause but I don't think I am writing it correctly.

Here is the code I have written:

```
SELECT d.department_id,d.DEPARTMENT_NAME,d.LOCATION_ID,d.MANAGER_ID,
e.first_name||' '||e.last_name AS Manager
FROM departments d
JOIN employees e ON d.MANAGER_ID = e.employee_ID
WHERE NVL(TO_CHAR(d.MANAGER_ID),'No Manager');
```

When i run it without the WHERE clause, I get the correct output except for that one missing department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a OUTER JOIN.

```
select  d.department_id,
        d.department_name,
        d.location_id,
        coalesce(d.manager_id, 'No Manager'),
        coalesce(e.first_name||' '||e.last_name, 'No Manager')  as manager
from    departments d
left outer join
        employees e 
        on d.manager_id = e.employee_id;
```

With a inner join, you will get only those departments which have a manager.

[LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db112/to_URL?remark=ranked&urlname=http:%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fcd%2FE11882_01%2Fserver.112%2Fe41084%2Fstatements_10002.htm%23SQLRF55393) ensures the query returns all records from the table on the left, i.e departments.

[COALESCE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions030.htm#i1001341) is similar to [NVL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions119.htm#SQLRF00684) and is standard across different DBMS, while NVL is Oracle specific.